# change date format in asp

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I cannot get the date format correctly in dynamic sql statement, after trying various ways of handling it. I need some help with the date format.

i am having a posting date field which is stored in sql db as yyyy-mm-dd format..and it displays in the asp web page as mm-dd-yyyy..i need to display the date in dd-mm-yyyy format..is there any way to do this?

this is my sql query:

```
SELECT CR.Name AS country,C.Name,C.[Name 2],C.[E-Mail],[Pre-Assigned No_], [Posting Date], SIH.[Currency Code], SIH.[Shipment Method Code],[Total Boxes],[ARE Net Wt],[ARE Gr_Wt], SIH.[Shipping Agent Code], SIH.[Payment Terms Code] FROM [Sales Invoice Header] SIH 
INNER JOIN [Country_Region] CR ON CR.Code = SIH.[Country of Final Destination] 
INNER JOIN [Customer] C ON C.No_ = SIH.[Sell-to Customer No_] WHERE SIH.No_ = 'PEXP1213-540'
```

Comment: Please check http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatdatetime.asp out and see if any of those samples help you format the Date in the Asp side instead of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to replace direct use **106**  or **105** and get the desired format
`SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 106)` – dd mon yyyy

so ur query look like

```
select  CR.Name as country,C.Name,C.[Name 2],C.[E-Mail],[Pre-Assigned No_], 
convert(varchar,[Posting Date], 106) AS [Posting Date], SIH.[Currency Code], SIH.[Shipment Method Code],
[Total Boxes],[ARE Net Wt],[ARE Gr_Wt], SIH.[Shipping Agent Code], SIH.[Payment Terms Code] from [Sales Invoice Header] SIH 
inner join [Country_Region] CR On CR.Code = SIH.[Country of Final Destination] 
inner join [Customer] C on C.No_ = SIH.[Sell-to Customer No_] where SIH.No_ = 'PEXP1213-540'
```

Also can do on codeBehind:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;             // Use current time
string format = "dd mm yyyy";            // Use this format
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));
```

Answer (score 0):

please tried with this query

```
select  CR.Name as country,C.Name,C.[Name 2],C.[E-Mail],[Pre-Assigned No_], 
replace(convert(varchar(12),[Posting Date], 103), '/','-') AS [Posting Date], SIH.[Currency Code], SIH.[Shipment Method Code],
[Total Boxes],[ARE Net Wt],[ARE Gr_Wt], SIH.[Shipping Agent Code], SIH.[Payment Terms Code] from [Sales Invoice Header] SIH 
inner join [Country_Region] CR On CR.Code = SIH.[Country of Final Destination] 
inner join [Customer] C on C.No_ = SIH.[Sell-to Customer No_] where SIH.No_ = 'PEXP1213-540'
```

**Note : Here [Posting Date] column is string, so need to just display.**